# IE11 ignores X-Frame-Options after redirect

Tags: internet-explorer-11, facebook-iframe, x-frame-options

I have a web application that is opened via a Facebook Messenger app. On mobile it's opened in Facebook Messenger's webview, on desktop it opens in an iFrame.  This works in all browsers except IE11.

We are setting an X-Frame-Options header of 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com'.  When the application is first loaded in the iFrame it loads with  no issues.  Then the application responds to a request with a 302 and redirects.  It's the page that gets redirected to that shows the error "This content cannot be displayed in a Frame".  There is no error in the console like there usually is when  iFrame content is blocked in other browsers.

Is there some aspect of redirecting in an iFrame that IE11 does not support?

More detail of application:
This is a Django server-side rendered web app using JS on the client.  I'll try to break down the order of operations:

Request 1: GET to endpoint1 which returns document - this is displayed in the iFrame successfully

Request 2: POST to endpoint1 from JS on the client

```
const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('psid', thread_context.psid);
        formData.append('tid', thread_context.tid);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function (event) {
            if (this.status !== 200) {
                handleError(this);
                return;
            }

            window.location.href = this.responseURL;
        };
        xhr.onerror = handleError;

        xhr.open('POST', postUrl);
        xhr.send(formData);
```

Response is status code 302 with a location header

Request 3: GET to the location returned in the 302 response.
The response is status code 200 and includes the document in the body.
This causes the xhr.onload above to fire and then calls the `window.location.href` to redirect to the new location returned previously.

Request 4: GET as a result of updating the `window.location.href`.  Response is status code 200.  This is when the browser displays the "content cannot be displayed in a Frame" message.

Each one of these requests includes the X-Frame-Options header of 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.messenger.com' in the response.

Comment: You had mentioned that after app get loaded it responds a request with 302. can you try to provide some more information about that request. like which code you used for it. how did you try to run it? or you can provide a sample code with steps. We will try to run it and try to produce the issue.

Comment: I'll try to add more detail to my post to help.  I can't easily put together a sample app or allow anyone public access to reproduce unfortunately.

Comment: I believe the root of the problem is that apparently IE does not support the responseURL property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) and therefore it's undefined.  It seems that maybe the final request ("Request 4") is perhaps a refresh and isn't the redirected location.  So I need to figure out how to properly get the redirected location in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the "content cannot be displayed in Frame" message was a red herring.  The problem is really due to setting:

```
window.location.href = this.responseURL;
```

In IE and perhaps older versions of Edge [responseURL is not a supported property of XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL).  Additionally it doesn't seem possible to get the request URL after a 302 in IE.  As a result my solution will be to rewrite our usage of returning the 302 to begin with and instead return a JSON response with the URL to redirect to.

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had fine the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark your solution as an accepted answer (after 24 hrs) for this thread may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes I had planned to mark this as the accepted answer once the 24 hours is up, thanks!